# Scrapy selenium middleware memory leak

Tags: mysql, selenium, memory-leaks, scrapy

I'm using a selenium middleware in my scrapy crawler:

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class JSMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        dcaps = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
        service = ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--web-security=false']
        dcaps = {'handlesAlerts': False, 'javascriptEnabled': True, 'takesScreenshot':False}
        dcaps["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
                                                      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36")
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcaps, service_args=service)
        self.driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
        self.driver.set_page_load_timeout(15)

    def ajax_complete(self, driver):
        jquery=False
        jscomplete=False
        try:
            jquery = (0 == driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active"))
        except WebDriverException:
            pass

        try:
            if driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") == "complete":
                jscomplete = True
        except WebDriverException:
            pass        
        return jquery & jscomplete

    def process_request(self, request, spider):        
        self.driver.get(request.url)      
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                                             self.ajax_complete, "Wait till loaded")
        body = self.driver.page_source
        response = HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)        
        return response
```

When the crawler is done it is waiting for new incoming jobs (basically retrieving job information via mysql).

The problem is, that phantomjs stays open and so it creates a memory leak. How and where should i close it?

Here is my spider:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from items import Item
from jobs import DoneJob
from model import CrawlerSettings
import re
from readability.readability import Document
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from urlparse import urlparse
from utility import MysqlConnector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):          

    def __init__(self, job):    
        self.counter = 0
        self.itemCounter = 0
        #Get the hosts
        self.job = job        
        allowedDomainsPre = job.url.split(",")
        allowedDomains = []        
        for domains in allowedDomainsPre:
            parsed_uri = urlparse(domains)
            domain = '{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
            print "DOMAIN"
            print domain
            allowedDomains.append(domain)

        self.allowed_domains = allowedDomains
        self.start_urls = allowedDomainsPre
        #Get job patterns
        jobPatterns = job.processing_patterns.split(",")
        allowedPatterns = []
        deniedPatterns = []
        for pattern in jobPatterns:
            if '-' in pattern:
                deniedPatterns.append(pattern.replace("-", ""))
            else:
                allowedPatterns.append(pattern)        

        self._rules = [
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(allowedPatterns), deny=(deniedPatterns)), callback=self.parse_items, follow=True)
                ]    
        self.name = job.id   
        self.settings = CrawlerSettings.normal_settings

    def closed(self, spider):
        #stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()
        itemCount = 0
        if self.itemCounter:
            itemCount = self.itemCounter  
        DoneJob.DoneJob().jobDone(self.job, itemCount)

    def parse_items(self, response):           
        item = Item()
        if self.counter >= 30:
            self.checkActive()
        #if the user wants a minimum description             
        if self.job.min_description > 0:            
            item['html'] = response.body  
            item['url'] = response.url
            #Job
            item['job'] = {}
            item['job']['id'] = self.job.id
            item['job']['user_id'] = self.job.user_id
            item['job']['name'] = self.job.name
            item['job']['url'] = self.job.url
            item['job']['api'] = self.job.api
            item['job']['max_pages'] = self.job.max_pages
            item['job']['crawl_depth'] = self.job.crawl_depth
            item['job']['processing_patterns'] = self.job.processing_patterns
            item['job']['days'] = self.job.days
            item['job']['ajax'] = self.job.ajax
            item['job']['min_description'] = self.job.min_description  
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'html.parser')        
            article = Document(soup.prettify()).summary()
            article_soup = BeautifulSoup(article) 
            text = re.sub(' +', ' ', article_soup.get_text().rstrip())
            text_length = len(text.split(' '))            
            if text_length > self.job.min_description:
                self.counter = self.counter + 1
                self.itemCounter=self.itemCounter+1
                return item
        else:
            item['html'] = response.body  
            item['url'] = response.url
            item['job'] = {}
            #Job
            item['job']['id'] = self.job.id
            item['job']['user_id'] = self.job.user_id
            item['job']['name'] = self.job.name
            item['job']['url'] = self.job.url
            item['job']['api'] = self.job.api
            item['job']['max_pages'] = self.job.max_pages
            item['job']['crawl_depth'] = self.job.crawl_depth
            item['job']['processing_patterns'] = self.job.processing_patterns
            item['job']['days'] = self.job.days
            item['job']['ajax'] = self.job.ajax
            item['job']['min_description'] = self.job.min_description     
            self.counter = self.counter + 1
            self.itemCounter=self.itemCounter+1
            return item


    def checkActive(self): 
        self.counter = 0      
        mysql = MysqlConnector.Mysql()
        db = mysql.getConnection();
        cur = db.cursor();
        cur.execute("SELECT status FROM job WHERE id=" + str(self.job.id))
        for row in cur.fetchall():            
            status = int(row[0])
            break  
        db.close() 
        if status == 3:
            raise CloseSpider(reason='Job cancelled')
```

And here is my init:

```
from jobs import GetJob
import time
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import task

def schedule():
    jobs = GetJob.Job()
    jobs.getJobs()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    t = task.LoopingCall(schedule)    
    t.start(15)
    reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use signals to do some actions when the spider ends:

```
class JSMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        ...
        crawler.signals.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        # actions when spider ends
        ...
```

Comment: Just thinking: Multiple crawlers can run at once -> will this solution not interrupt then the other crawlers?

Comment: every job (every time your run a spider) creates its own process, they don't interfere with each other.

Comment: let me know if it helps

Comment: But from where do i get the crawler? (sry - not so used with python)